# Get 2 render instead of one when apply find()

Tags: reactjs

I want to get some values inside Link, using ant design, table component.
To render a values in ant design exists:

```js
  {
    title: 'Action',
    key: 'action',
    render: (text, record) => (
      <span>
        <a style={{ marginRight: 16 }}>Invite {record.name}</a>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </span>
    ),
  },
];
```

I made my code using above example:

```js
 {
      title: 'Animal',
      dataIndex: 'animal',
      key: 'animal',
      render: () => (
        <Link>{
          animals.filter(id => id.animal_id === myId).map((item, i) =>{
            return <a href="">{myArray.find(u => u.id === item.myarray_id).name}                      </a>
          })
        }
        </Link>
      ),
    },
  )
```

The issue is, that i get this:

```js
dogdog
catcat

// the output values are doubled
```

Why i get repeated values ?

Comment: what is in `animals` variable ?

Comment: `const a = [
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jill',
    id: '25'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    id: '288'
  }
]
const b = [
  {
    title: 'alfa',
    a_id: '2'
  },
  {
    title: 'beta',
    a_id: '25'
  }
]
`@Gabriel Petroli, there are some array like these above. Not them, but almost like this, only with different data.